# Gradle Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

my issue is, when I try to run my JavaFX project with the command `gradlew run` I receive an error: **`Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main`**
I tried to set the main class with

`sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']` and/or
`mainClassName = "sample.Main"`

Do I miss something really important?

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

//sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:16'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:16'
    implementation group: 'mysql',
            name: 'mysql-connector-java',
            version: '8.0.24'
}

application {
    mainClassName = "sample.Main"
}
```

**Project Explorer**

[image]

A few more information.

**JDK**: OpenJDK-16 (version 16.0.1)

**IDE**: IntelliJ 2021.1.3

I just want it to start. I don't know if I just can't google problems or missunderstand something from gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting sourceSets.src.main.java to 'src' but your folder structure is src.main. Either you change your folder structure to src/main/java or set proper sourceSets.src.main.java.srcDirs to 'src/main'

e.g:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your fast answere. I tried what you wrote, but when I build my project  I get a new Error now: ```A problem occurred evaluating root project 'swt2_bibliothek'.
> Could not get unknown property 'src' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.```
The structure stayed the same since I created this project.

Comment: try `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main']`

Comment: Well the build from gradle is succsefully but when I want to ```gradlew run``` I have my Error from above: ```Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Main
```

Comment: Can you try setting `mainClassName = 'main.sample.Main'`

Comment: Tried it inside ```application{}``` and outside same error